# "Item Template" function of Kendo Grid filter is showing Undefined

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to add a filter to a column of Kendo Grid.It should be as below :

[image]

I tried with

```
columns.Bound(e => e.Status).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Multi(true)).CheckAll(false)` and `.Filterable(filterable => filterable.Extra(false).Mode(GridFilterMode.Menu)
```

It looks like this

[image]

I could not capture checkbox check actions, also I need to disable buttons and look and feel is different from the actual. So I thought I can go with ItemTemplate option. This is the code I tried

```
columns.Bound(e => e.Status).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Multi(true).ItemTemplate("funcStatus")) <script>function funcStatus()
{
alert("hello");
}</script>
```

and it is showing "funcStatus" is undefined. What is wrong with ItemTempalte function? How can I change look and feel of filter popup?

Comment: ItemTemplate usually returns html to be rendered: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.filterable.itemTemplate

Comment: I tried with html content initially, as it not worked i just kept alert just to check the function triggering.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Messages` property for `Filterable` like this:

`.Filterable(filterable => filterable.Messages(m => { m.IsFalse("Invalid"); m.IsTrue("Valid"); m.Info("Show items with value:"); })`

So now instead of the filter saying 'True' it will say 'Valid'. Also `m.Info` is just the description of your filters, if you want that.

I grabbed this grid from [Telerik's example](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/filter-menu-customization) and trimmed it down to a very basic grid for this example. This is how you can use it.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.EmployeeViewModel>()    
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns => {
        columns.Bound(e => e.Status).ClientTemplate("#= Status ? 'Valid' : 'Invalid' #");;   
    })    
    .Filterable(filterable => filterable.Messages(m => { 
        m.IsFalse("Invalid"); m.IsTrue("Valid"); m.Info("Show items with value:"); 
    })   
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("FilterMenuCustomization_Read", "Grid"))
     )
)
```

Click [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/localization#filter) to see Telerik's documentation for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the information,I tried the mentioned solution, it is not working. Filter the options are still "True", "False" not "Valid","Invalid".

Comment: Could you edit your original post and add the code for your grid? Maybe we can find the issue from that.

Answer (score 0):

I used BindTo function to get Filter names.

```
columns.Bound(e => e.Status).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Multi(true).CheckAll(false).BindTo(
                            new[]{
                                new { Status = "Valid" },
                                new { Status = "Invalid"  }
                            }))
```

and in Filterable the code should be like this

```
.Filterable(filterable => filterable
                    .Extra(false)
                    .Mode(GridFilterMode.Menu)
                    )
```

Note : Status is a string property, the values mapped to Status column and filter names should be the same for the filter to work without discrepancy.

Comment: I am able to get the filter however i have additional functionality on top of it. Can I add id's to check boxes through Bind To function??. I need to retain previous selection of filter on click of Reset.